# replace all NA values in first 4 columns of data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame with 6 columns.

How do I replace all the NA values in the first 4 columns with a 0?

I have tried:

```
grades[is.na(grades), 1:4] = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The `is.na` is applied on the full dataset and it gives a matrix with dimensions equal to the original dataset.  So, it is better to subset the dataset and apply the `is.na` on the first four column to get a logical matrix and then use the same subset of data to assign the TRUE values to 0

```
grades[1:4][is.na(grades[1:4])] <- 0
```